# Workaround for UIKit bug with pullView?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

When quickly swiping to delete rows on my table view, I get the following message in the console and the inability to see the row actions I've configured for my cells. However, if I continue to swipe (again, no visible row actions, just a registered touch), I am able to, for example, delete the row by swiping all the way to the left.

```
[Assert] The pullView is not in a view hierarchy. This is a UIKit bug.
```

This behavior is not ideal and is confusing/inconvenient for users who want to be able to quickly swipe to delete a few rows at a time. Is there a workaround for this UIKit bug?